# Reference to hypothesis about breast sexual attractiveness?

Tags: human-biology, evolution, human-anatomy, human-evolution

Some time ago there was a hypothesis published,suggesting evolution made breasts mimic buttocks for either primitive men being attracted to women when they started to walk on two legs, or to discourage sexual intercourse from behind for other reasons I can’t remember. I can find many posts about this online, but I can’t find any reference to the original idea. Can anyone provide information about this?

Comment: Do breast ressemble buttocks so much?! You can use [google scholar](https://scholar.google.com) for example to search for papers. Among the first results I got there are [Furnham and Viren 2007](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/content/sbp/sbp/2007/00000035/00000001/art00001) and [Anderson 1988](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0162309588900118). Note by the way that you are confounding the term theory with hypothesis.

Comment: What is the difference between theory and hypothesis? arent they both unconfirmed?

Comment: @Remi.b those researchs you linked are interesting, but they arent the one I'm looking for. The one I'm looking for states the opposite to the second one.

Comment: In science, a theory is a set of hypotheses that are highly supported by many evidences (e.g. theory of gravity, theory of evolution, ...). The definitions of these terms are up the the field of philosophy of science but we have one post on Biology.SE that explain them brielfy ([here](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/40579/is-evolution-a-fact)).

Comment: I know it is not exactly what you were looking for that's why I posted it as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: We use a different meaning for theory in my country. In the universities I attend, in subjects like research methodology or philosophy of science, theories are unconfirmed or unvalidated statements, which might have support, but not conclusive evidence. I dont think we are the only ones who uses the term this way, because I've seen the term being used in this way amongst american  Psychologists for example. What is different to a hypothesis or a theory is a scientific law. I didnt mean theory as a synonymous of scientific law, if that's what you understood from what I wrote

Comment: I have modified your question, improving the English and scientific statement. If I have changed your meaning please say. I am still not sure this is on-topic. It is not really a question about science — you just want a reference. However I will leave others to decide on that.

Comment: A scientific law differs from a scientific theory. A law does not attempt to explain a natural phenomena, they just posits a causality relationship (e.g. law of thermodynamic) while a theory attempts to explain a natural phenomena (e.g. theory of gravity). A hypothesis is a guess about nature (e.g. the hygiene hypothesis). Anyway, it is not the place to discuss this. Just have a look at any intro course to philosophy of science or philosophy of knowledge (or even just wikipedia) or ask questions on Philosophy.SE. Note that the term theory is often misused in the popular culture.

Comment: and what do big and red lips look like? why do men and women have equally large big lips? your theories are only components of a larger image, and in a concensus of all theories on breast shape, that theory is only one dimension of it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Eventually, I found it, here it is:

> In considering the human animal, zoologists proposed that the human
>   female is the only primate that possesses permanent, full-form breasts
>   when not pregnant. Other mammal females develop full breasts only when
>   pregnant. The zoologist Desmond Morris proposed that the rounded shape
>   of a woman's breasts evolved as frontal, secondary sex characteristic
>   that is a sexual-attraction counterpart to the buttocks, and so
>   encouraged frontal copulation, the reason being that while other
>   primates mate by means of the rear-entry position, the upright,
>   bipedal human being was likelier to successfully copulate face to face
>   in the missionary position.

https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/uflgy/why_are_breasts_so_attractive_after_all_theyre/

Comment: *Pan paniscus* ([bonobo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bonobo)) also copulates face-to-face.

Comment: I said I was looking for a hypothesis which refered to that. That's the hypothesis I was looking for, I didnt say the hypothesis was confirmed or denied as being "right" or "wrong".